# How Come Visual Studio 2017 Jams on a Repair?

Tags: installation, visual-studio-2017, repair-install

I was trying to upgrade Visual Studio 2017 with the latest update, but then it complained about a Windows 10 SDK that it couldn't download. So, I cancelled the install. When I tried to run a repair install, it just hung at 0% on the "Acquiring XXXX..." message.

Answer (score 0):

Check your Event Log under Control Panel > Administrative Tools > Event Viewer > Windows Logs > Application Log. In my case, I found that the VSS service and the Software Protection Services were halted. When I started those up in the Services Control Panel (Control Panel > Administrative Tools > Services), the Repair Install in Visual Studio 2017 suddenly started working again.